# Excel: How to avoid a question mark triggering the duplicate rule

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In MS Excel, I have a few columns filled with text values. And for it, I created a conditional formula to highlight whenever there is some value repeating more than once in the same column.

But whenever I type a question mark `?` in any cell in that column, excel (conditional formula) highlights it as a duplicate value, even when there is no other question mark in that whole column. How to avoid it?

Conditional formula I'm using:
`=countif(a1:a10, a1)>1`

Note: I know I can escape the question mark with ~, but I do need to type exactly a question mark in one of the cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can prefix `~` when `*` or `?` is found.  The `~` tells the countif we want the literal string and not the wildcard:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$10,SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"*","~*"),"?","~?"))>1
```

[image]

Comment: Though all other answers are also solutions, as they all addressed my problem, but the solutions they gave didn't fit my scenario. And so, they're solutions, for some other scene, nevertheless.

Comment: So, for my circumstances, I chose this answer as a 'chosen answer'. Thanks ji.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to lock your range references in conditional formatting formulas. Using the formula exactly as you have it means the conditional formatting won't work the way you expect. For cell `A1`, it'll look at the range `A1:A10` but, for cell `A10`, it'll look at the range `A10:A19`. Your original formula should have at least set the row numbers as absolute instead of relative values: `=countif(a$1:a$10, a1)>1`.

[image: Fail]

---

Regardless, you need to change the formula. [`COUNTIF()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34) accepts wildcards. `?` means a single character and `*` means any number of characters. When the cell value is the literal string `?`, it counts the cells in the range that contain a single characters. Instead, try this:

```
=AND(A1<>"",SUM(--EXACT(A1,A$1:A$10))>1)
```

[`EXACT()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/exact-function-d3087698-fc15-4a15-9631-12575cf29926) checks if two inputs are an exact match and returns either `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Adding the `--` in the front is a quick way of converting TRUE to 1 and FALSE to 0 because it's "negative negative". You could also use `1*` instead of `--`. You just need some math operation. The whole function, then, counts all the exact matches within the range. Since it doesn't use wildcards like `COUNTIF()`, the liter string `?` is just treated like a literal string. Adding the `A1<>""` requirement lets it ignore blank cells.

[image: GreatSuccess]

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Though it solved the problem of `?` being considered as duplicate. But now all the blank cells in the range (from a1 to b10) are highlighted by the conditional formula. Even if the range contains only one blank cell (same as earlier ,when only one/single question mark was being treated as a duplicate).

Comment: Though this answer too is an alternate solution, which might apply/be desirable in a diff scene, but not mine, not today. Today the anwer given by @scott Craner fitted my circumstances fully well. Yet this solution given here too was a unique one.

Comment: @BathindaHelper I appreciate your feedback and have updated by answer to address blank cells. [Scott Craner's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1686752/348859) has the additional benefit of working in older versions of Excel, too. It's a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

The COUNTIF function accepts wildcards, so when the cell contains `?`
it does a wildcard search.

If the problem is only with the question mark, you could test for it:

```
=IF(a1="?", false, countif(a1:a10, a1)>1)
```

Comment: Though this formula did solve the problem of `?` being treated as a duplicate by the conditional formula. But now even two occurrences of `?`s are not being detected as duplicates. Also now, the first occurrence of the duplicate is highlighted, whereas I wanted all the occurances to highlight (as it did before), or at least 2nd occurrence to highlight, not the 1st one.

Comment: Though this answer too is an alternate solution, which might apply/be desirable in a diff scene, but not mine, not today. Today the anwer given by @scott Craner fitted my circumstances fully well. Yet this solution given here too was a unique one.